# Mvc 4 Routing in sitecore WebForms application System.Web.AsyncStepCompletionInfo.RegisterBeginUnwound NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I'm trying to get Mvc4 routing set up in an existing sitecore WebForms application.

I've added the following:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("WebForm", "WebForm", "~/WebForm1.aspx");
```

Navigating to `/WebForm` gives the following exception:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Web.AsyncStepCompletionInfo.RegisterBeginUnwound(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean& operationCompleted, Boolean& mustCallEndHandler) +32
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +516
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +287
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same exception when enabled MVC on Sitecore CMS. I found that the reason is that Sitecore accepts only IAsyncHttpHandler routes.

Technically `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes` pipeline wraps your handler with `RouteHandlerWrapper` and invokes it through async `RouteHttpHandler` that throws the exception in case your handler is not inherited from `IHttpAsyncHandler`.

To avoid it you should register your routes after `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes` pipeline in Sitecore.Mvc.config:

```
<initialize>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
    <!-- Register your routes here -->
</initialize>
```

Alternatively you can make you handler to work asynchronous:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // do your work here
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    protected delegate void AsyncProcessorDelegate(HttpContext context);

    private AsyncProcessorDelegate _processorDelegate;

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        _processorDelegate = new AsyncProcessorDelegate(ProcessRequest);
        return _processorDelegate.BeginInvoke(context, cb, extraData);
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        _processorDelegate.EndInvoke(result);
    }
}
```